# Porting existing Cordova app into Android Studio

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I have an existing Cordova app that I've been testing in Xcode.
The workflow was simple:

```
1. cordova build ios
2. open xcode project file in Xcode
3. either run in simulator or build directly to device
```

I'm tyring to figure out the same for running an Android build for testing.

```
1. Installed Android Studio
2. Installed and configured Android SDK 19
3. When I setup my run configuration, it says:
"AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"
```

I've followed the trail to Cradle, migrating existing project to Cradle, but have been unsuccessful so far in figuring out how to take an existing Cordova project and getting it to run on my device.
Is there a workflow as easy as Xcode's 1...2...3... for Android?

Comment: Did you add the platform android and build the project?

Comment: Try to import your android project in Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, android studio isn't officially supported by cordova/phonegap yet, you should use the ADT.

But here you can read how to work with android studio beta and cordova/phonegap
http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/using-android-studio-beta-with-cordova-phonegap/